# compare password and confirm password is not working in my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

compare password and confirm password is not working in my code

```
 [Required]
 [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
 [DataType(DataType.Password)]
 [Display(Name = "Password")]
 public string Password { get; set; }

 [DataType(DataType.Password)]
 [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
 [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The Password didn't match.")]
 [Compare("Password")]
 public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I am using `Compare` attribute here to match my password and confirm password, when i put the wrong password in confirm password..it didn't show me error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are checking if input string is not longer than `100` and if it is, you are returning a message, that passwords didn't match?

Comment: @sem, Please! check to compare attribute.. it's not working.

Comment: @mjwills, I am using 'Compare' Attribute here to match my password and confirm password, when i put the wrong password in confirm password..it didn't show me error.

Comment: @avi add your last comment to question, because basically it is your question/problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show error message, when `ConfirmPassword` is incorrect, you should specify error message inside `Compare` attribute (not inside `StringLength` attribute):

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The Password didn't match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Also I would suggest to use `nameof` to specify comparing property name:

```
[Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "The Password didn't match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```